# How to create own layers in tensorflow.js

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow.js

I am new to tensorflow.js and I was wondering if you are able to create a Neural Network that looks like this:

[image: Neural Network]

Up to this point I have only seen dense layers (tf.layers.dense) but I do not know if it is possible/how to create this input layer.

Comment: What do you try to achieve by creating such an architecture ?

Comment: I dont want it to mix up the 2 inputs that belong together with the other 2 inputs. Does that make sense or is it ok to use a dense layer there too?

Comment: I do think that you can achieve what you want with dense layers. But can you show the kind of inputs you have and the kind of response you're waiting for ?

Comment: The inputs are supposed to be results of soccer games and the output should be the result of the next soccer game. It's predicting soccer results

Comment: Even if you do not use a fully-connected in the first layer, you will continue to mix the data.
It really is what interests you to get a prediction from it.

You can perfectly use an fc in the first layer, the only thing you will do is mix the data "before".

Answer (score 1):

A fully connected neural network also called dense layers can be used to represent the architecture above. Actually with a fully connected, the relation between the input and the output is a linear one `WX+b` which means that if for some values of W, the weights are 0, there will no connection between the some values of the input and some node of the hidden layers.

One can initialize the weights of the neural network when defining the network architecture this way:

```js
const model = tf.sequential()

const kernel = tf.eye(3).expandDims(-1).minimum(tf.ones([3, 2])).transpose([0,2,1]).reshape([6, 3])
kernel.print()
model.add(tf.layers.dense({inputShape: [6], units: 3, weights:[kernel], useBias: false}))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 8}))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 2}))
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.14.1/dist/tf.min.js"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to predict using a variable match entry you can use an LSTM.

Because virtually all inputs are the same "nature", I personally would make the weights between the models shared.

```
const model = tf.sequential()
model.add(tf.layers.timeDistributed({
   layer: tf.layers.dense({units: 4}),
   inputShape: [3, 2],
}));
model.add(tf.layers.flatten())
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 8}))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 2}))
```

But a similar conclusion as my comment is reached. You will fuse the matches in a deeper layer but they will continue to merge. I do not see the need to use a network other than a conventional one, a classic MLP. This restrictions are interesting when you need to simplify the problem or restrict the problem (for instance the importance of a frame in video. First use dense-timedistributed to extract features and later use dense to fuse features).

The problem of these solutions is that the order of matches does matter, to avoid this problem you can use this architecture (fuse using sum):

```
const model = tf.sequential()
model.add(tf.layers.timeDistributed({
   layer: tf.layers.dense({units: 4}),
   inputShape: [3, 2],
}));

model.add(tf.layers.sum(0))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 8}))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 2}))
```